# Why is there an extra gap printed by turtle in the pattern I'm trying to have it draw?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to draw an evenly spaced 10x10 square of randomly coloured dots with turtle graphics in python 3, while I've managed to get it mostly working, I can't figure out why an extra gap is generated every time the turtle is facing west and is told to turn north and back to the east even though that gap isn't created when turning north and to the west even though the code is pretty much identical?

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random


colour_list = [(198, 12, 32), (250, 237, 17), (39, 76, 189), (38, 217, 68), (238, 227, 5), (229, 159, 46), (27, 40, 157), (215, 74, 12), (15, 154, 16), (199, 14, 10), (242, 246, 252), (243, 33, 165), (229, 17, 121), (73, 9, 31), (60, 14, 8), (224, 141, 211), (10, 97, 61), (221, 160, 9), (17, 18, 43), (46, 214, 232), (11, 227, 239), (81, 73, 214), (238, 156, 220), (74, 213, 167), (77, 234, 202), (52, 234, 243), (3, 67, 40)]
screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)
tim = Turtle()
tim.speed('fastest')
column = 0

def fill_circle():
    tim.color(random.choice(colour_list))
    tim.begin_fill()
    tim.circle(10)
    tim.end_fill()

def ten_dots():
    for _ in range(9):
        tim.pendown()
        fill_circle()
        tim.penup()
        tim.forward(50)

def change_direction():
    if tim.heading() == 0.0:
        fill_circle()
        tim.setheading(90.0)
        tim.forward(50.0)
        tim.setheading(180.0)
    elif tim.heading() == 180.0:
        fill_circle()
        tim.setheading(90.0)
        tim.forward(50.0)
        tim.setheading(0.0)

while column < 10:
    ten_dots()
    change_direction()
    column += 1





screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: `circle()` isn't centered on the turtle position; it's drawn entirely to the left of the turtle.  So on your lines going to the left, the circles are lower on the screen than on lines going to the right.  Use `dot()` instead of `circle()` - this also lets you get rid of the `begin_`/`end_fill()` calls.

Comment: (Temporarily commenting out the `pendown()` / `penup()` commands would make it clearer just what's going on.)

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `circle()` but we have to adjust the y coordinate by the radius.  Whether that's an addition or subtraction depends on the direction of drawing:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import choice

RADIUS = 10

colour_list = [
    (198, 12, 32), (250, 237, 17), (39, 76, 189),
    (38, 217, 68), (238, 227, 5), (229, 159, 46),
    (27, 40, 157), (215, 74, 12), (15, 154, 16),
    (199, 14, 10), (243, 33, 165),
    (229, 17, 121), (73, 9, 31), (60, 14, 8),
    (224, 141, 211), (10, 97, 61), (221, 160, 9),
    (17, 18, 43), (46, 214, 232), (11, 227, 239),
    (81, 73, 214), (238, 156, 220), (74, 213, 167),
    (77, 234, 202), (52, 234, 243), (3, 67, 40),
]

def fill_circle():
    tim.color(choice(colour_list))

    y = tim.ycor()
    tim.sety(y - (RADIUS if tim.heading() == 0.0 else -RADIUS))
    tim.begin_fill()
    tim.circle(RADIUS)
    tim.end_fill()
    tim.sety(y)

def ten_dots():
    for _ in range(10):
        fill_circle()
        tim.forward(50)

def change_direction():
    heading = tim.heading()

    tim.backward(50)
    tim.setheading(90.0)
    tim.forward(50.0)

    tim.setheading(180.0 - heading)

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

tim = Turtle()
tim.hideturtle()
tim.speed('fastest')
tim.penup()
tim.goto(-250, -250)

column = 0

while column < 10:
    ten_dots()
    change_direction()
    column += 1

screen.exitonclick()
```

However, as @jasonharper suggests (+1), this is easier drawn with `dot()`, which draws centered on the turtle and for which we can simply swap out `fill_circle()` to instead be:

```
def fill_circle():
    tim.color(choice(colour_list))

    tim.dot(RADIUS*2)
```